# iOS app crashing at UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, exc-bad-access

I am tring to create a PDF from the current view. Below is my code.

```
func createPdfFromView(saveToDocumentsWithFileName fileName: String) -> CGPDFDocument?
{
    let pdfData = NSMutableData()
    var pdfDoc: CGPDFDocument!
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, self.view.bounds, nil)
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()

    guard let pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil }

    self.view.layer.render(in: pdfContext)
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()

    if let documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first {
        let documentsFileName = documentDirectories + "/" + fileName
        debugPrint(documentsFileName)
        pdfData.write(toFile: documentsFileName, atomically: true)
        let localUrl  = "file://"+documentsFileName as CFString
        let pdfDocumentRef = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(nil, localUrl, CFURLPathStyle.cfurlposixPathStyle, false)
        pdfDoc = CGPDFDocument(pdfDocumentRef!)
        return pdfDoc
    }

    return nil
}
```

But my app is frequently crashing at 
`UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()` with EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. Not sure why this is happening. I am new to Swift.

Answer (score 0):

For me this occurred when I was also trying to release it with CGContextRelease after:

```
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
CGContextRelease(pdfContext);//<-comment out this to solve
```

I only needed `UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();`
For some reason even calling CGContextRelease AFTER calling EndPDFContext, still caused EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the `EndPDFContext` line, probably an async issue.

Answer (score 0):

My view contained an `MKMapView` - this caused the crash. Interestingly, it didn't crash on simulator.